# Erro de conversão de numérico para numérico

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Tenho uma stored procedure no banco de dados que altera um registro de um cliente, inserindo a data na qual ele será visitado e o entrevistador que realizará a visita.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Captacao_InsereDadosAgendamento
@DATA_ENTREVISTA DATETIME,
@ENTREVISTADOR NVARCHAR(30),
@CGC NVARCHAR(14)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        CLIENTES
    SET
        DATA_AGENDAMENTO = @DATA_ENTREVISTA,
        ENTREVISTADOR = UPPER(@ENTREVISTADOR)
    WHERE
        CGC = @CGC
END
```

Mas quando eu executo a procedure, mesmo que passe os três parâmetros corretamente, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Nenhum dos parâmetros da procedure ou da tabela é do tipo numeric. 
O que eu faço para corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Qual é o tipo das colunas data agendamento, entrevistador e cgc?

Comment: data agendamento é datetime, entrevistador é nvarchar(30) e cgc é nvarchar(14)

Comment: Quais são os dados que estão sendo passado nas variaveis? Acredito que o problema possa estar no datetime. Tente excluir ele da sua procedure para fazer um teste

Comment: tentei passar só o nome do entrevistador e dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Pode mostrar como está chamando a proc e quais os valores?

Comment: Eu executo a procedure no SQL Manager Lite e passo os parâmetros direto no pop-up que ele abre: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M5foCBETcb2vxzy5EmbaFybsfdJx4AwO/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou colocando a resposta para poder encerrar a pergunta.

Conversando com um dos analistas, encontramos uma trigger que era acionada no insert ou update nessa tabela de clientes, para realizar os tratamentos dos dados inseridos na tabela. Como nenhum desses dados é usado nessa procedure, decidimos usar os comandos DISABLE TRIGGER e ENABLE TRIGGER. E funcionou. O novo código ficou assim:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Captacao_InsereDadosAgendamento]
@DATA_ENTREVISTA DATETIME,
@ENTREVISTADOR NVARCHAR(30),
@CGC NVARCHAR(14)
AS
BEGIN
    DISABLE TRIGGER CLIENTES.CLIENTES_triu ON CLIENTES;  
    UPDATE
        CLIENTES
    SET
        DATA_AGENDAMENTO = @DATA_ENTREVISTA,
        ENTREVISTADOR = UPPER(@ENTREVISTADOR)
    WHERE
        CGC = @CGC;
    ENABLE TRIGGER CLIENTES.CLIENTES_triu ON CLIENTES;          
END
```

Obrigada aos que tentaram ajudar!